# What alfanumeric string generated as access token in instagram

Tags: instagram, access-token

Can i get Instagram Access Token's syntax? What is used to constructing access token. They are use ip address, location, timestamp..

Comment: user_id, application unique_id and code ( which is return when you application is authenticate ) are those three detail is use for the Access Token.

Comment: What is code string?

Comment: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code


When you authenticated application with your account at that time in the redirect URL in the query string ( ?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx ) that is the code.

Comment: Thanks...But it's not my answer

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but can you tell me what you want?